# How to uninstall TensorFlow completely?

Tags: 14.04

I accidentally installed TensorFlow for Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled.
When I installed with Linux 64-bit CPU only, I am getting Segmentation fault while importing tensorflow from python console.

Comment: Did you try first importing numpy and then importing tensorflow?

Answer (score 18):

Depends on how you install it considering the fact that there are multiple ways to do it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html). Most generic way people do it is through pip, check using:

```
sudo pip show tensorflow
```

Uninstall using:

```
sudo pip uninstall protobuf
sudo pip uninstall tensorflow
```

Install it using:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: You shall not `sudo pip`.

Comment: @runDOSrun why not?

Comment: why do you need protobuf to uninstall tensorflow?

Comment: Why protobuf???

Comment: @PseudoAj Why ??

Comment: @CharlieParker [because of this](https://askubuntu.com/a/802594/349837) but in this particularly case might be fine.

Comment: How to do without sudo. I do not have sudo access

Comment: @PseudoAj  everyone is waiting for your reply

Comment: @DheerajMPai @runDOSrun Since this was my local machine, I was using `sudo` to install tensorflow systemwide. So to remove it I was using `sudo` as well. Now, if you didn't use sudo to install it you need not use it.

Comment: @SmallChess simply to make sure dependency and cache are removed`

Answer (score 5):

When running in `conda` env or any virtual env sudo doesn't work. So you can use:

```
python3 -m pip uninstall protobuf    
python3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
```

`python3 -m` is safest way to ensure that you are using `pip3` and not `pip2`.